# Is there a better way to combine those two function as good practice

Tags: javascript, date

I use split to trace space and "|" between date.
Eg. convertSpaceDatetimeToJSDate(03-09-2021 04:58 PM),convertToJSDate(30-08-2021 | 4:22 PM);
Is there better way to combine or any good practice?

```js
let DateFormatHelper = function () {
  this.convertToJSDate = (dateStr) => {
    const dateStrParts = dateStr.split("|");
    const date = dateStrParts[0];
    const time = dateStrParts[1];
    const dateParts = date.split("-");
    const day = dateParts[0].trim();
    const month = dateParts[1].trim();
    const year = dateParts[2].trim();
    const newDateStr = `${year}-${month}-${day} ${time}`;
    return new Date(newDateStr);
  };

  this.convertSpaceDatetimeToJSDate = (dateStr) => {
    const dateStrParts = dateStr.split(" ");
    const date = dateStrParts[0];
    const time = dateStrParts[1];
    const dateParts = date.split("-");
    const day = dateParts[0].trim();
    const month = dateParts[1].trim();
    const year = dateParts[2].trim();
    const newDateStr = `${year}-${month}-${day} ${time}`;
    return new Date(newDateStr);
  };
};
```

Comment: Your snippet does not do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since only the splitter changes in those two functions, you can accept the splitter as a parameter and use as a single function

```
let DateFormatHelper = function () {
  this.convertToJSDate = (dateStr, splitter) => {
    const dateStrParts = dateStr.split(splitter);
    const date = dateStrParts[0];
    const time = dateStrParts[1];
    const dateParts = date.split("-");
    const day = dateParts[0].trim();
    const month = dateParts[1].trim();
    const year = dateParts[2].trim();
    const newDateStr = `${year}-${month}-${day} ${time}`;
    return new Date(newDateStr);
  };
};
```

**Sample Implementation**

```js
let DateFormatHelper = function () {
  this.convertToJSDate = (dateStr, splitter) => {
    const dateStrParts = dateStr.split(splitter);
    const date = dateStrParts[0];
    const time = dateStrParts[1];
    const dateParts = date.split("-");
    const day = dateParts[0].trim();
    const month = dateParts[1].trim();
    const year = dateParts[2].trim();
    const newDateStr = `${year}-${month}-${day} ${time}`;
    return new Date(newDateStr);
  };
  return { convertToJSDate };
};
console.log(DateFormatHelper().convertToJSDate('03-09-2021 04:58 PM', ' '));
console.log(DateFormatHelper().convertToJSDate('03-09-2021|04:22 PM', '|'));
```

Comment: This returns *null* for both calls in Safari. It returns an incorrectly parsed date in Firefox for the first call and *null* for the second. It relies on parsing a timestamp in an unsupported format using the built–in parser, so results are implementation dependent, which is easily confirmed by running in different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You may add a parameter to the function which is the date/time separator:

```
let DateFormatHelper = function (sep) {
    this.convertToJSDate = (dateStr) => {
    const dateStrParts = dateStr.split(sep);
    const date = dateStrParts[0];
    const time = dateStrParts[1];
    const dateParts = date.split("-");
    const day = dateParts[0].trim();
    const month = dateParts[1].trim();
    const year = dateParts[2].trim();
    const newDateStr = `${year}-${month}-${day} ${time}`;
    return new Date(newDateStr);
};
```

Usage:

```
DateFormatHelper('03-09-2021 04:58 PM', ' ');
DateFormatHelper('03-09-2021 | 04:22 PM', ' | ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current strategy of partially parsing the string to build another string (in an unsupported format) that is then parsed by the built–in parser is not a good idea.

Using the built–in parser is strongly discouraged for unsupported formats. Given that you're already parsing most of the string, it's much better to parse all of the string and pass the parts to the Date constructor directly, e.g.

```js
// Parse format 03-09-2021 04:58 PM and 30-08-2021 | 4:22 PM
function myParse(dateString) {
  let [D, M, Y, h, m, ap] = dateString.split(/\W+/);
  h = h % 12 + (ap.toLowerCase() == 'pm'? 12 : 0);
  return new Date(Y, M-1, D, h, m);
}

[ '03-09-2021 04:58 PM',
  '30-08-2021 | 4:22 PM'
].forEach(s => console.log(s + '\n' + myParse(s).toString()));
```